# Count number of child records in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame with the columns `parentId` and `id_x`. I am now trying to create a new column, which displays the number of related child(`id_x`) in  the parent entry. The related SQL query for one entry (id) would be `SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM node WHERE parentId="1234qwer"`. Is there a way to apply this for every row in a pandas dataframe? In the dataframe it could also be possible that a parent is a child of a higher parent.

EDIT:

Here is a sample of the data

```
df[["parentId", "id_x"]].head(4)

|               parentId               |                 id_x                 |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 |
|                 None                 | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 |
```

There are n `parentId` that can match the `id_x`. I now want to create a new column that counts/displays the number of `parentId` that match a specific `id_x`.

The result should look like the following:

```
 df[["parentId", "id_x", "Amount"]].head(4)

|               parentId               |                 id_x                 | Amount |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | 1      |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 | 0      |
|                 None                 | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | 2      |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 | 0      |
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, please post an example of the data (a few significant rows), both the input and your expected output.

Comment: I edited my initial question. Sorry, it's the first time that I'm asking a question here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As @joao said, post expected output of a sample data. [Avoid upload image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15239951).

Comment: @Corralien I changed the picture into code and provided the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with

```python
def node_counter(id_x, parent_ID):
        counter = 0
        for child in parent_ID:
            if child == id_x:
                counter += 1
        return counter
    
df['Amount'] = df.apply(lambda x: node_counter(x['id_x'], df['parentId']), axis=1)

df

|               parentId               |                 id_x                 | Amount |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | 1      |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 | 0      |
|                 None                 | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | 2      |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 | 0      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
>>> df
                               parentId                                  id_x
0  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2
1  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2  d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2
2                                   NaN  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3
3  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184
```

Output:

```
>>> df.assign(amount=df["id_x"].map(df["parentId"].value_counts()).fillna(0))
                               parentId                                  id_x  amount
0  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2     1.0
1  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2  d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2     0.0
2                                   NaN  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3     2.0
3  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184     0.0
```

Count the number of `parentId` unique values and map them to `id_x` then assign to the `amount` column of your dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, this results in an error: *Wrong number of items passed 13, placement implies 1*